# set project wide variable in rundeck to use in jobs

Tags: rundeck

is it possible to set sort of a project-variable in rundeck?

I am organizing jobs in projects, but the jobs are mostly the same and use the same values over and over again. If I could set variables per project, I could just copy jobs from project to project without having to adapt the same parameters over and over again...

like... path=/path/to/project
and use the variable path in jobs

Thanks, regards
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [global variable](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables) for that. You can define it on `framework.properties` file like `framework.globals.myvar=myvalue` or at project level (`project.properties` config) like `project.globals.myvar=myvalue`, to access it just use `${globals.myvar}` for steps, `@globals.myvar@` for inline-scripts or `$RD_GLOBALS_MYVAR` for scripts.

UPDATE:

In Rundeck 3.1/3.2/3.3/4.X the "project.properties" isn't a "file", is a config reachable/editable following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880550/10426011).

Comment: uh oh... greetings to cpt. obvious. Thx for pointing me to the corresponding docs.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k could you please have a look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879895/how-to-resolve-global-variables-in-rundeck

Comment: Done, also I added a note in this answer, thanks!