# How to resolve global variables in Rundeck?

Tags: global-variables, rundeck

I tried adding my variable in:

> {Rundeck-Path}/etc/project.properties

as

```
project.globals.test=myvalue
```

And trying to access it from an inline script as

```
echo @globals.test@
```

however it does not print the value, instead I get an empty string, any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `project.properties` config isn't a "real file" anymore (on Rundeck 2.X and 3.0.X it does), that information is stored on the internal Rundeck Database.

To add globals on the `project.properties` follow these steps:

1. Go to your project.
2. Click on the "Project Settings" > "Edit Configuration" (left panel).
3. Then click on the "Edit Configuration File" button (up to right).
4. Add your project global variable like in the config: `project.globals.myglobal=hello` in a new line and Save.
5. Now if you print the `@globals.myglobal@` in any inline-script step, you can see the [global content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DjUH.jpg).

Comment: Argh, lost a couple of hours fiddling with the project.properties ...
Thanks again!

Comment: could you please answer these questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891763/how-to-use-rundecks-database-from-a-custom-plugin
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73891723/rundeck-step-level-statistics