# Rundeck Step Level Statistics

Tags: notifications, statistics, execution-time, rundeck

Rundeck provides a great deal of statistics on its running jobs.
Example: Average execution time, success rate, with the ability to send notifications when a job execution time is longer than average etc..

Is there a way to have similar statistics on a step level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract relevant information about a previously executed step from this API call:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#execution-state

Example

```
{
"executionId": 1058,
"serverNode": "localhost",
"nodes": {
    "localhost": [
        {
            "executionState": "FAILED",
            "stepctx": "1"
        }
    ],
    "SCZ-Env1": [
        {
            "executionState": "NOT_STARTED",
            "stepctx": "2"
        },
        {
            "executionState": "NOT_STARTED",
            "stepctx": "3"
        }
    ]
},
"executionState": "FAILED",
"updateTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
"startTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:19Z",
"completed": true,
"endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
"allNodes": [
    "SCZ-Env1"
],
"stepCount": 3,
"steps": [
    {
        "duration": 14923,
        "parameterStates": {},
        "executionState": "FAILED",
        "stepctx": "1",
        "startTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:19Z",
        "updateTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
        "id": "1",
        "endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
        "nodeStates": {
            "localhost": {
                "duration": 14923,
                "meta": {
                    "failureReason": "PluginFailed"
                },
                "executionState": "FAILED",
                "startTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:19Z",
                "updateTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
                "endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z"
            }
        },
        "nodeStep": false
    },
    {
        "duration": -1,
        "parameterStates": {},
        "executionState": "NOT_STARTED",
        "stepctx": "2",
        "startTime": null,
        "updateTime": null,
        "id": "2",
        "endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
        "nodeStates": {
            "SCZ-Env1": {
                "duration": -1,
                "executionState": "NOT_STARTED",
                "startTime": null,
                "updateTime": null,
                "endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z"
            }
        },
        "nodeStep": true
    },
    {
        "duration": -1,
        "parameterStates": {},
        "executionState": "NOT_STARTED",
        "stepctx": "3",
        "startTime": null,
        "updateTime": null,
        "id": "3",
        "endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z",
        "nodeStates": {
            "SCZ-Env1": {
                "duration": -1,
                "executionState": "NOT_STARTED",
                "startTime": null,
                "updateTime": null,
                "endTime": "2022-10-11T08:29:34Z"
            }
        },
        "nodeStep": true
    }
],
"targetNodes": [
    "SCZ-Env1"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Right now doesn't exist that kind of statics at the step level, but you can "see more" at the moment of execution.

For that, run the jobs in debug mode: before running your job, check the green "Run Job Now" button and click on the triangle at the left, then select "Run with Debug Output" and then run the job.

In this way, you can see all internal processes (e.g: the creation of options, env vars, etc...) in the job output.