# How to Use Rundeck's Database From a Custom Plugin

Tags: database, plugins, rundeck

I am writing a custom Rundeck plugin that requires persisting data in a DB.
Is it possible to use Rundeck's database from the sdk to write/retrieve data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to read the db source info from {Rundeck-Dir}/server/config/rundeck-config.properties

```
dataSource.driverClassName
dataSource.url
dataSource.username
dataSource.password
dataSource.dbCreate
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's possible but at your **own risk**, writing directly on the database may cause a backend integrity problem (or some issues after a big Rundeck upgrade) so, the best way is to use another persistent method like retrieve information using the [Rundeck API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#api-reference-version-41) and store the specific plugin info on a JSON file / own database.

Comment: You are definitly right about you concerns